# Bitcoin theft from Coinbase account being hacked

Tags: coinbase.com, theft

Not sure anything can be done, but I want to know how they did it and to prevent them using the coins if at all possible. Here are the details of the theft.

You just sent 0.8495 BTC (worth $604.46 USD) to 16fYQiV2cdHuycGo3eibE5JSKvndY2z8Gw.

~6.40GMT 29th December.

I only access coinbase via the android app, did this get compromised somehow?

Comment: Do you install a lot of obscure/shady apps on your android phone, especially without reading what permissions they accept? You can read this - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55666/can-there-be-malicious-apps-on-google-play

Comment: No, im pretty careful on what I install and lean on apps.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you happen to know who owns `16fYQiV2cdHuycGo3eibE5JSKvndY2z8Gw`, there is no way for you to get back your Bitcoin. You could try to raise awareness that this address holds stolen coin, but I don't see how that would benefit you in any way. What happened is essentially the Bitcoin equivalent of somebody taking your dollar bills from your wallet without you noticing.

You might want to get in touch with the Coinbase support and see if they have a policy regarding such events. You might also want to use more secure methods of storing your bitcoin in the future, such as password protected desktop wallets, paper wallets, or at least an online wallet with two way authenticated spending access.

As of how exactly the attacker gained access, I cannot tell from the information provided. It could either be by having compromised your android device or by having compromised your account at Coinbase directly.

Comment: yea clearly a learning experience and a warning to anyone wanting to store coins in the cloud. Contacted coinbase they have asked some questions so waiting response, will post back if I learn anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same thing happen to my Coinbase account. I did use the two part authentication and did not enable the api key. however the api key was enabled. Coinbase does nothing and says I logged into to a coinbase phishing site, but I only logged into coinbase from my bookmarked link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever turned on API access to your account? I seem to be seeing a lot of issues losing bitcoin after enabling the API.

Comment: No - but after some digging yesterday i realised that the android app I am using (the official coinbase one) turned it on for me. I think this is the weak point that was exploited although would be interested to understand how...